# Is it possible to display included source code

Tags: include, universe, rocket

Have a subroutine with a $include file item in it. One of the common variables held in the $include file isn't being updated.

Wondering if somehow the include isn't being included, hence question regarding displaying source code including $include source code.

Comment: What programming language? What compiler or interpreter? Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot, perhaps showing the source code of your routine (with four spaces before each line)

Comment: Is it an SB+ common variable? I am not aware of a way to view the source code for an include. If you could add a brief sample of the code and the context for what you're doing, perhaps I can still help though.

Comment: Basile, Universe by Rocket Software, if you are unaware of multivalued databases then you will have zero idea on this one I'm afraid

Comment: Hey webthaumaturge, straight uvBasic, vaguely remember being able to print out full source with include code, but think it was either R83 or one of the VAR versions,perhaps prime information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UniVerse an include is a bit of source that is pulled in at compilation time and added to the source of your program.

If you have something like this...

```
$INCLUDE INC.BP OBJ.LOGGING.MESSAGES
```

The compiler will use the VOC entry "INC.BP" as the file and read in all of the lines from the record "OBJ.LOGGING.MESSAGES" as if they were entered in the source code.

You should be able to view or edit this as you would any other bit of source code. If you can compile your code than the include file at least exists.

Comment: Thanks Van, as it turned out code was being executed but variable wrongly named in the include. Went the long way of cutting and pasting into a single Notepad++ file. Problem was in the include from another include, got to love spaghetti code.